# Python SqlAlchemy generate table classes pragmatically

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given a list of table names, I'm trying to generate SqlAlchemy db table classes programmatically. Here is what I do:

```
def generate_table_class_list(engine):
    base = declarative_base(engine)
    table_names = ['table_a', 'table_b']
    table_classes = dict()
    for table in table_names:
        table_classes[table] = generate_table_class(table)
    return table_classes

def generate_table_class(base, table_name):
    return type(table_name, (base,), dict(__tablename__ = table_name,
                                          __table_args__ = {'autoload' : True}))
```

When I run generate_table_class_list(engine), I got following error messages:

```
/opt/packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.pyc in first(self)
    829         try:
    830             if row is not None:
    --> 831                 return self.process_rows([row])[0]
    832             else:
    833                 return None

/opt/packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.pyc in process_rows(self, rows)
    759         else:
    760             return [process_row(metadata, row, processors, keymap)
    --> 761                     for row in rows]
    762 
    763     def fetchall(self):

TypeError: row must be a sequence
```

I used similar scripts to do this before with the same version sqlalchemy and it works. However, it doesn't work this time.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after several days researching and testing, I figure it out. When I create an engine, I set the cursor class as SSDictCursor. When I swtiched to SSCursor, it works fine with me, even though I still don't why SSDictCursor breaks my code.

Answer (score 0):

DictCursor is also working. Only thing is you need to specify it when you create the cursor. Please check this one.

```
connectString = 'mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}?charset={}'.format(userDB, passDB, hostDB, portDB, databasename, 'utf8mb4');
engineConnect = create_engine(connectString, connect_args= {'autocommit' : True});

conn = engineConnect.connect();

with conn.connection.cursor(pymysql.cursors.DictCursor) as cursorForFind:
    cursorForFind.execute(queryString, (username));

    (rowCnt, rowVal) = (cursorForFind.rowcount, cursorForFind.fetchone());
```