# Python SQLAlchemy create dymanic unknown tables

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I have a question about dynamicly creating tables with SQLAlchemy. I do not know the tables names when the python server script starts.

How this works is, I have written a client app that collects data, then using REST(server) and Requests(Client) I push the data to the server component. I catch the data at the server API point and successfully write them(params) into the database, that's all good.

My problem comes in when I have a client at a new location. The server should create a new table in the database(server) for each location the client reports into the server.

The clients automatically create a new table with the name based on the location specified. However the client will always just work/read/write to one table at a time until it stops.

**Client DB:**

```
Database>
   Location1>
      device(String(17))
      location(Text)
      data1(Text)
      data2(Text)
```

**On the server** I would like to dynamically create a new table in the same database for the new unknown location reported by the client. Therefore on the server I would have a table per "location" and a database filled with locations.

**Server:**

```
database = "mysql://user:pwwd@localhost/SERVER"
metadata = MetaData()
engine = create_engine(database)
Base = declarative_base()

class Records(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'records'
    device = Column(String(17), primary_key=True)
    data1 = Column(Text())
    location = Column(Text())
    data2 = Column(Text())

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine, checkfirst=True)
```

**The server structure I want to create is as follows:**

```
 Database>
       Location1>
          device(String(17))
          location(Text)
          data1(Text)
          data2(Text)
       Location2>
          device(String(17))
          location(Text)
          data1(Text)
          data2(Text)
       Location3>
          device(String(17))
          location(Text)
          data1(Text)
          data2(Text)
```

***Question:** I found a fair amount of posts about this topic, [Good Post Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25375425/python-sqlalchemy-generate-table-classes-pragmatically) but in this post I struggle to understand how I would create the columns for said table. And then how I would make a call outside the class (ORM) to 'unknown_table1' when 'unknown_table2' was dynamically created after 'unknown_table1'.

**I find out if the table already exists with:**

```
from sqlalchemy.engine.reflection import Inspector
inspector = Inspector.from_engine(engine)
    def known_location(self, _loc):
        global inspector
        global dyntable
        _know_tables = inspector.get_table_names()
        if _loc not in _know_tables:
            create the table and add the data to it on your own!.
```

any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Please tell me how I can improve it.

I setup a standard database connection, then connect to a server table and create it if it doesn't exist.

```
_location = "SERVER"

Records = Table(_location, metadata,
    Column('device', String(17), primary_key=True),
    Column('data1', Text()),
    Column('location', Text()),
    Column('data2', Text()),
    extend_existing=True
)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine, checkfirst=True)
```

I then have a sequence through which the data is posted to the server using REST. I then parse the parameters into variables which I then pass to a def below.

```
def collector(_device, _data1, _data2, _loc):
    global session
    global metadata
    Records = Table(_loc, metadata,
        Column('device', String(17), primary_key=True),
        Column('data1', Text()),
        Column('location', Text()),
        Column('data2', Text()),
        extend_existing=True
    )
    check = exists().where(Records.c.device==_device)
    if check == True:
        updt = update(Records).where(Records.c.device==_device).values(data1=_data1, location=_loc, data2=_data2)
        session.add(updt)
        session.commit()
    else:
        Create_new_Table(_loc)
        ins = Records.insert().values(debice=_device, data1=_data1, location=_loc, data2=_data2)
        session.execute(ins)
    session.commit()
    session.close()
```

If the table does not exist then I call a function called "Create_new_Table()"... below.

```
def Create_new_Table(_loc):
    global engine
    global metadata
    global Base
    Records = Table(_loc, metadata,
        Column('device', String(17), primary_key=True),
        Column('data1', Text()),
        Column('location', Text()),
        Column('data2', Text()),
        extend_existing=True
    )
    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine, checkfirst=True)
    Records.create(engine, checkfirst=True)
```

Please let me know if you think I can improve anything.